# Setting a WNDCLASS style for GTK widgets

Tags: winapi, opengl, gtk, gtk3

I have a custom widget class inheriting from `GtkWidget` that I'd like to use as an OpenGL drawing surface under Win32.

Now I need a Win32-Window as the drawing area with the `CS_OWNDC` flag set in the window class. Does GTK+ use Win32-Windows in a fashion that makes this possible, and if so, how can I modify the `WNDCLASS` structure used?

**Edit:** As the number of device contexts is not as limited in newer versions of Windows, simply acquiring and never releasing a DC seems to do the trick. But of course this is just a workaround, so I'll keep this thread open in case somebody has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to get into the way of GTK+'s internal window management. GTK+ has it's own kind of OpenGL widget called "GtkGLExt", which is implemented in a add-on library for GTK. There's also GtkGLArea which is an older implementation and deprecated.

Use GtkGLExt for all things OpenGL. https://developer.gnome.org/gtkglext/stable/

Comment: Unfortuanely, GtkGLExt is not available for GTK 3. There exists a port, but it its X11-only.

Comment: @datenwolf GtkGLArea is in GTK+3 since 3.16.